# Error when linking opencv2.framework to Swift Xcode project

Tags: ios, swift, opencv, xcode7

I'm trying to import opencv2 framework to my Swift project. The problem is that the project couldn't be built. Following are some of erros:

```
"cv::medianBlur(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)", referenced from:
"cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::Mat const&)", referenced from:
"cv::contourArea(cv::_InputArray const&, bool)", referenced from:
```

In my Swift project, I have a .pch file named ProjectName-Prefix.h with content:

```
#ifndef MyScanner_Prefix_pch
#define MyScanner_Prefix_pch

#ifdef __cplusplus
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif

#endif /* MyScanner_Prefix_pch */
```

How can I fix the errors? Actually, I saw some other projects on Github written in Swift which also integrate opencv2 and I tried to import all necessary frameworks, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Did you include the libc++.dylib ?

Comment: Yes, I did. In Xcode 7, the lib's name is "libc++.tbd"

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try an alternative approach which is [cocoapods](https://cocoapods.org/). While adding the opencv framework manually, I myself spent too much time to resolve these kind of issues but did not get succeed. so I recommend you to go for pods;

```
pod 'OpenCV', '~> 2.4.10'
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, but it doesn't fix the problem. I found out the cause which is an issue of supported architecture

Comment: If you use `pod  'OpenCV', '~> 3.0.0'` you won't run in to the "libjpeg.a" issue. But in Xcode 7 you do need to disable Bitcode in Build Settings under Build Options.

Answer (score 0):

By comparing architectures between my project and the one downloaded from GitHub, I found out the solution. The project from GitHub is an outdated project (3 years ago) and it uses arm7 and arm7s while my project is created in Xcode 7 with an additional architecture (arm64). Arm64 is mandatory for new apps and the framework on cocoapods support arm64 (many thanks to @Shoaib). However, there is another issue with a library named "libjpeg.a" that we have to solve it manually. People who have the same problem like me can check [this link](http://code.opencv.org/issues/4052) for the issue of "libjpeg.a"